# QGIS function layer_name in fieldcalculator batch-mode

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, batch, function, layer-name

Working with QGIS 3.10, I want to use the `@layer_name` function in batch mode for all layers in a project. In individual cases, I do this via the field calculator.

I also found the script for the field calculator in batch mode in the toolbox
but somehow I don't get that configured.

Can someone explain how to do this?

What I mean is that fieldcalculation in batch-mode
for all layers:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question/tags to show which software you're working with.

Comment: Sorry it's for using QGIS 3.10..

Comment: You "want to use the `@layer_name` function" ... great, but: to do what? `@layer_name` is a variable, so there are quite a lot of things you can do with it. Please revise your question to make it clear what you want to achieve - explain what you do "in individual cases" via field calculator. And maybe add a screenshot. Otherwise, it's dificult to guess what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to run the fieldcalculator as a processing tool from your processing toolbox:

[image]

Then click on "Run as batch process".

Then fill it with your layers, then choose your fieldname, click on autofill, then choose your fieldtype, click on autofill, insert your expression, click on autofill. Dont miss the last column, to add an output (not visible in my screenshot). Finally run the process.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Field calculator`.
2. In the field calculator dialog window, click Run as batch process... (bottom left)
3. In the dialog window that opens, for input layer select `autofill...`, click `Select from Open Layers…`, than Select All
4. Fill in the values for `field name`, `Result field type`, `Result field length` - you can set it once and than use `Fill Down` so it will be copied to all layers (see arrows in the screenshot)
5. In the `Formula` field, paste `@layer_name`, use `fill down` to copy it to the other rows.
6. Finally, set an output path in the last column called `calculated`. Click the three points `...`, select a folder, define a filename (like `output`) and when done, in the dialog that opens, chose `Fill with numbers` to get different filenames like `output1`, `output2` etc.: see screenshot

[image: D:\Uni\Lehrveranstaltungen\Digital_Skills_P8\GIS_Unterlagen\Fallbeispiele\Koenigslandschaft_MA_Sachsen_thuringen\Screenshot_2021-03-14 GIS als Hilfsmittel zur Analyse räumlicher Strukturen im östlichen Sachsen und Thüringen des 10 und f[...].png]